# Metadata Rest API for custom objects

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, http

Is it possible to create and update custom objects using rest? I seen different questions that suggest it isn't yet available without using a client or SOAP but I need to be able to access it through http calls alone. (I know I can probably do it for soap but I'm attempting to make it as least complicated for me as possible).

Comment: Are you trying to create *records of custom objects* or the *definition* of the custom object itself? The former is the REST API, the latter is the Metadata API.

Comment: Both in a sense, although if I can create the objects within salesforce then use the api to add records then I can happliy do that but I have no idea how to create the objects within salesforce

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott As David mentioned, you will need to mix the approaches here. You will need to utilize [Metadata API](https://sforce.co/2DMsCch) to create the *definitions* and utilize SOAP or REST to create the *records* within those objects.

Comment: @JayantDas Is there anyway to create custom objects in Saleforce UI?

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott Yes absolutely. You can always create custom objects in Salesforce UI if you are admin/developer. This [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectcreate_task_parent.htm&type=5) will be a good place to start with.

Comment: @JayantDas Thank you so much, I wish I found this sooner. Would you make an answer to this post so I can accept it and make it resolved?

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott Done. Added the relevant links for defining the objects as well as adding records in those objects. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussions in the comments, you have two requests here:

1. To create custom objects using API/UI
2. To create records within those custom objects

You can achieve these using the different APIs available.

[Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) is what you will need to create custom objects if you want to utilize an external client. You can also create custom objects from [Salesforce UI](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_objectcreate_task_parent.htm&type=5).

For creating records within those custom objects, you will need to use either [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) or [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm).

The links in the answer should help you get started.